# QGIS 3 processing script won't show gui when executed from editor

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-3, gui

Different from QGIS 2, when I execute a processing script from the *Processing Script Editor* by pressing the Play-button in QGIS 3 it's GUI is not created. Seems to me that the `initAlgorithm()` method is not called?

[image]

Everything's fine with the GUI when double clicking the same script it in the processing toolbox:

[image]

Am I missing something? Issue?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Which QGIS 3 version are you using?

Comment: 3.2.3, and I just saw that it works when trying it with the provided script template, but I copied most of the code in the template into my script, so I wonder what the difference is :-(